# Is it possible to comment/mark out certain folders in a collection while running via postman runner

Tags: postman

I am working on a collection arranged in different folders w.r.t. different business component scenarios. Now some of the scenario folders might be alternative/redundant paths for the same workflow. Is it possible to somehow unmark/comment and mark/uncomment some of these alternate path folders in postman runner to get varying runs easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so one way is to arrange the collection folders in following way to facilitate the same:

```
- Main Collection
   - Workflow1_Folder
   - Workflow2_Folder
   - Workflow3_Folder
   - Workflow4_Folder

- UnmarkedWorkflows Collection
   - Workflow2_Alternate_Folder - this will contain the steps that are alternate to ones on Main>Workflow2_Folder
   - Workflow3_Alternate_Folder - this will contain the steps that are alternate to ones on Main>Workflow3_Folder
```

Only the Main folder needs to be run.
If/when required Workflow2_Alternate_Folder could be moved into Main folder from the UnmarkedWorkflows Collection followed by moving Workflow2_Folder to UnmarkedWorkflows Collection. Then Main collection could be run to test an alternate path for the same Use Case.